# division and logarithmic calculation in AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I have three column file like this below. I want to divide column 3 by column 2 (ignoring headers) and print it in column 4. Also, I want to calculate the log2 value of column4 and print it in column5 as shown below.

```
head my_file.txt
this    is header   
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:-    76.5382 76.34220209
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:-    60.0702 62.1887549
chr11:18266979:+::chr11:18269194:+  15.4004 1558.282058
```

I am trying by awk, is giving less output and repeated lines.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR > 1 {$4 = $3 / $2}1' my_file.txt |awk -F"\t" 'FNR > 1{a = log($4)/log(2); print $0"\t" a} OFS="\t"'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=my_file.txt FNR=15) fatal: division by zero attempted
this is header
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:-    76.5382 76.3422020852288    0.997439    -0.00369948
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:-    76.5382 76.3422020852288    0.997439
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:-    60.0702 62.1887548960591    1.03527 0.0500071
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:-    60.0702 62.1887548960591    1.03527
```

This is my desired output.

```
this is my desired header
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:-    76.5382 76.34220209 0.9974392145    -0.003699170995
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:-    60.0702 62.1887549  1.035267985 0.05000426549
chr11:18266979:+::chr11:18269194:+  15.4004 1558.282058 101.1845185 6.66084476
```

Comment: Yes. it worked perfect! Thank You Very Much!

Comment: awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==1 {print $0, "col4", "col5"; next} {if ($2 != 0) {$4 = $3 / $2; $5 = log($4) / log(2)} else {$4 = "NaN"; $5 = "NaN"}} 1' my_file.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below command:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==1 {print $0, "col4", "col5"; next} {if ($2 == 0) {$4 = "NaN"; $5 = "NaN"} else {$4 = $3 / $2; $5 = log($4) / log(2)}} 1' my_file.txt
```

Basically, the above command:

- checks for the first row (header) and adds "col4" and "col5" as column names.
- For the remaining rows, it calculates the division and log2 values if column 2 is not zero; otherwise, it sets "NaN" as the value for columns 4 and 5. By setting the values of columns 4 and 5 to "NaN" when column 2 is zero, the script avoids division by zero errors and provides a clear indication that the result of the calculation is not a valid number.

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/UniqueAlphanumericDeals#main.sh)***

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "column4", "column5"; next} {print $0, $3/$2, log($3/$2)/log(2)}' my_file.txt
```

For output_file:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "column4", "column5"; next} {print $0, $3/$2, log($3/$2)/log(2)}' my_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

Output:

```
this    is header    column4 column5
chrX:73829232:-::chrX:73831065:-    76.5382 76.34220209 0.997439 -0.00369917
chrX:73827985:-::chrX:73829067:-    60.0702 62.1887549 1.03527 0.0500043
chr11:18266979:+::chr11:18269194:+  15.4004 1558.282058 101.185 6.66084
```

**EDIT:**

Check first dividing by non-zero:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "column4", "column5"; next} $2!=0 {print $0, $3/$2, log($3/$2)/log(2)} $2==0 {print $0, "undefined", "undefined"}' my_file.txt > output_file.txt
```